# How to run a background service periodically with small intervals in android?

Tags: java, android, service

My application has a service that scans for bluetooth device.
This scan is controlled by the U.I.
Once turned on, it goes on indefinitely but needs to sleep in between implicitly to conserve battery. What should i do? :
1) AsyncTask with while loop that uses sleep();
2) ScheduledExecutorService
3) Handler
4) Alarm + Bound Service + Broadcast receivers 
or what?
P.S. - the intervals might vary from few seconds to 1 hour.

Comment: Use an [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) with setInexactRepeating(...)

Answer (score 0):

Should it continue scanning when your app is in the background?  If so, use an alarm with a started service; if not, use a handler in the activity.